# Calculate Bezier Curve on the fly

Tags: java, math, bezier, andengine

I'm new in java,

I 'm working with code (from andengine) that generates me position coordinates of graphic element in 2d based on Bezier Quadratic (which i'm giving percentage of whole animation).    mX1, mX2, mX3 (initialized in constructor) are the points which describes control points of that curve.

```
public void updatePosition(final float pPercentageDone, final IEntity pEntity) {
    final float u = 1 - pPercentageDone;
    final float tt = pPercentageDone*pPercentageDone;
    final float uu = u*u;

    final float ut2 = 2 * u * pPercentageDone;

    /* Formula:
     * ((1-t)^2 * p1) + (2*(t)*(1-t) * p2) + ((t^2) * p3) */
    final float x = (uu * this.mX1) + (ut2 * this.mX2) + (tt * this.mX3);
    final float y = (uu * this.mY1) + (ut2 * this.mY2) + (tt * this.mY3);

    pEntity.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

what i want to achieve is to extend generation that Bezier from 3 points to n points (n>4) 
How could i do it most effective way ?

That should work like this :

```
//constructor
public Modifier (ArrayList<PointF> pInputPoints,....)
```

and when in Arraylist are 8 points( = 2 Quadratic Bezier Curves ), then final curve is described by two Bezier Curves merged together , and then updatePosition will recalculate new position from all points )

Comment: which one from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve

Comment: This should act as Collection of Quadratic Bezier Curves, editied in original post